# TrackPad Preferences

Tags: trackpad

I own a MacBook Pro mid 2010, and formatting it and upgrading it to the High Sierra is no longer displaying TrackPad preferences so I can adjust it, the menu I am referring to is in this order: System Preferences - > Trackpad, it is worth remembering that I am referring to the Trackpad of the Macbook and there is a bluetooth, when I click on the Trackpad option inside the preferences menu there is written that No trackpad found and gives me the option to activate bluetooth? My Trackpad is installed on Mac it is not bluetooth. Sorry for my bad English.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's odd. Can you open System Profiler and post a screenshot of the USB device tree?

Comment: I added pictures

Comment: macOS recognizes that a keyboard and trackpad are connected, but the Trackpad Preference Pane is missing. That sounds like a defect in the OS of High Sierra that you've just installed. I'd reboot into the Recovery Partition, and reinstall the system software.

Comment: Ok I'll try this, I'll come back later to tell you if it worked.

Comment: Is there a battery installed/detected by macOS? Please see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/331198/151636