# High Sierra not detecting Trackpad - Trackpad settings

Tags: trackpad

Recently upgraded to High Sierra, Trackpad only searches for bluetooth trackpad,

And shows "**No trackpad found**".

My trackpad functions very well and it's not defective so it's not a hardware issue, I can see the relevant information of my trackpad in system information.

I want to edit settings for my 13" 2011 Macbook Pro internal trackpad/touchpad.

**On Sierra I had:**

[image: Sierra Trackpad]

**Now on High Sierra I have:**

[image: HS Trackpad]

**System Information:** (Taken from Sierra)

[image: Sys Info High Sierra]

**System Information:** (Taken from High Sierra)

[image: Sys Info Sierra]

**My Mac:**

[image: Mac]

Comment: If your internal trackpad doesn't show in settings it's usually a hardware or battery issue. Did you drop the laptop recently? Is the battery swollen?

Comment: @patrix The battery was starting to swell so I removed it from my laptop, before I installed High Sierra I was updating from Lion and trackpad settings were managable there, why can't I manage settings on High Sierra? I just want to move windows with three fingers :)

Comment: I really found nothing googling why am I the only on with this issue, I can see how it is unclear what I'm asking because it has never happened before but it's really clear what I'm asking, if you need info just let me know and I fill you in, please do not close my questions

Comment: I read Allan's answer, he said He's assuming the OP has at least 2013 mac, why is that?! is this because my macbook is old? but I can see my trackpad in system information (connected over usb) and it functions very well I just want to enable three finger option to move window

Comment: This is why your question was initially marked as unclear and then as a dupe - you're leaving out **critical** details - details that help us help you.  Remember, we're not there to look over your shoulder.

Comment: @Allan hehe ofc, sorry about that :) so would you recommend to downgrade to another OS?

Comment: No, the first recommendation is to include all relevant details into your question. Including screenshots of the relevant part of your System Info, Preferences etc

Comment: This post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305040/trackpad-preferences has the exact same symptoms and one of the commenters said to reinstall.  There was no follow up as to whether it worked.  Before doing that, I would try adding a new user (with admin rights) to see if the problem is with your profile.

Comment: @Allan I tried a diff user (with admin rights), reinstalled HS (without erasing) then erased volume and installed HS again, disabled SIP, reset NVRAM. None of them worked, I guess I should try Sierra? :(

Comment: Oh wait, Sierra doesn't support APFS.......

Comment: @patrix Just installed Sierra, the problem is with High Sierra, I also updated all screenshots, all are taken from my Mac.

Comment: The only difference between Sierra and High Sierra in System information of the Trackpad seems to be the Location ID.

Comment: Aaaand I just found out, three finger drag has been removed, and can't enable it since Mouse and Trackpad settings on my mac are seperate.

Comment: Just for grins and giggles, turn Bluetooth off to see if it discovers it.

Comment: nope lol didn't work :D

Comment: **Removing the battery** causes the "Trackpad not found" issue, and reconnecting the battery will let Trackpad preferences work; please see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/331198/151636. This **is not a duplicate** of https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/235365/151636 because that asker's trackpad doesn't work, whereas this asker's trackpad does work.

Comment: @chrstphrchvz You are awesome dude! I can't wait to install HS again and buy a battery! If this was the problem then I moved to El Capitan for nothing lol. Thanks so much for sharing this :D